# Firebase Nested Snapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a db ref that holds "messages" and I have a get at the creation of the class to get the whole list of messages but I also wanted to add a listener to limitToLast(1) so I get updates for each added message:

```
ref.child("messages").child(mConversation.getConversationId()).limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (mRecyclerViewAdapter != null) {
                    Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to cast the following snapshot node into my object the fields are all null

```
{
  10={
    message=This is my message
    senderId=thisIsAUniqueId
  }
}
```

And for the list I was able to get all of the messages for a conversation and cast the snapshots into my Message object:

```
 ref.child("messages").child(mConversation.getConversationId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot message : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        messageList.add(message.getValue(Message.class));
                    }
```

And these get cast fine, the snapshot node for a given snapshot in that list looks like this:

```
{
  {
  message=message1
  senderId=id1
  }
}
```

Just wondering how I can grab the object out of the former node, because that is what I get when I call snapshot.getValue() but I also can't know at runtime what the value is going to be to be able to getChild("10") then cast that to my Message object. Essentially my problem is limitToLast is giving me one level too high and I'm not sure how to get its child and be able to cast to my Message class. I had thought I could use the snapshot.getChildren() then get the first and only child and getValue(Message.Class) but I get back an iterator so it's not super simple to get the first child

The entire db as JSON:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "conversation1" : [ {
      "message" : "message1",
      "senderId" : "personId1"
    }, {
      "message" : "message2",
      "senderId" : "personId2"
    } ]
  },
  "users" : {
    "personId1" : {
      "conversations" : [ {
        "conversationId" : "conversation1",
        "participantIds" : [ "personId1", "personId2" ]
      } ]
    },
    "personId2" : {
      "conversations" : [ {
        "conversationId" : "conversation1",
        "participantIds" : [ "personId1", "personId2" ]
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. Can you edit your question to show the JSON from the Firebase console at `/messages/$conversationId` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: There we go, got it uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem, at least if the first snippet in your question doesn't work, while the second does.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

You need to handle this in your `onDataChange`, just like you're doing in the second snippet. So:

```
ref.child("messages").child(mConversation.getConversationId()).limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (mRecyclerViewAdapter != null) {
            for (DataSnapshot message : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Message message = message.getValue(Message.class);
                ...
```